# Hexadecimal in [] operator

Tags: c++, arrays, hex

I found some article and I saw this:

```
// Capture vendor string
char vendor[0x20];
memset(vendor, 0, sizeof(vendor));
*reinterpret_cast<int*>(vendor) = data_[0][1];
*reinterpret_cast<int*>(vendor + 4) = data_[0][3];
*reinterpret_cast<int*>(vendor + 8) = data_[0][2];
```

This line: `char vendor[0x20];`.
Why threre are hexadecimal and may I use octal value?

[CPUID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/intrinsics/cpuid-cpuidex?view=vs-2019)

Comment: For whatever reason whoever wrote it believed that hexadecimal would be more expressive. And what do you mean "why I need plus 4 and 8 in `reinterpret_cast`"? If the task at hand requires addition, there aren't very many alternatives to addition, in C++. As far as octal, decimal, or hexadecimal, all numbers are alike, in C++. You are free to write all numbers in binary, even, if you so choose. Your question has too many question. One question per stackoverflow.com question, please.

Comment: You are welcome to use octal yes.  What happened when you tried it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why threre are hexadecimal

Because the author chose to use hexadecimal. As you can see, 0x20 is quite "round" in hexadecimal, as it has only one non-zero digit.

> may I use octal value?

Yes. Where-ever you can use an integer literal, you can use any of the available base representations. Binary, decimal, octal and hexadecimal are the options.

P.S. The example is technically broken in standard C++, because it fails to align the buffer, so it is not a good example to use for learning the language. I appears though that it is written specifically for x86 processors, which do work with unaligned operations.

A correct way to write this would have been to use an array of integers, copy the values, and then reinterpret the result as characters when reading.